# function callback using std::bind causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++, boost

I have a class (let's call this "Common") that is used to create timers and call a member function from another class (let's call this "A") when the timer expires. 
The general idea is this:
- A calls a function from Common passing it a pointer to the member function that is to be executed when the timer expires
- Common stores the pointer to the function in a map with key of timer id
- When the timer hits, the map is searched for the matching key and then the associated function is called.

Here is the code for A:

```
void A::setTimer()
{ 
   std::function<void(void)> handler = std::bind(&A::onEventFunc, this);
   pCommon->scheduleTimer(&handler);
}
```

onEventFunc is a public function of class A that does something when the timer expires.

Here is the code for Common:

```
static void timerHandler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void uc)
{
   map<timer_t*, std::function<void>(void)>*)::iterator iter = 
                                globalTimerMap.find((timer_t*)si->si_value.sival_ptr);
   if (iter != globalTimerMap.end)
   {
      std::function<void>(void)>* handler = iter->second;
      (*handler)();
   }
}

Common::schedulerTimer(std::function<void>(void)* handler)
{
   // uses Linux timer_create and timer_settime
   // code for these excluded EXCEPT the relevant lines
   sa.sa_sigaction = timerHandler;

   // bunch of other code here for timer_create and timer_settime

   // insert into map
   globalTimerMap.insert(pair(&timerid, handler);
}
```

This all compiles and runs just fine UNTIL it hits the (*handler)(); line which gives a segmantation fault.

I am new to boost and Linux programming and any knowledge that I have with C++ was gained from on the job training. This makes me believe that I am doing something really silly/stupid but I just don't know what it is. Is what I am trying to do even supposed to work?

Answer (score 7):

The following line:

```
std::function<void(void)> handler = std::bind(&A::onEventFunc, this);
```

This creates a local variable on the stack (local to your `setTimer` member function). What this means is your pointers in your map are all pointing to invalid memory.

I would change your map to store actual `std::function` objects rather than pointers.
If you insist on storing pointers in your map, you will need to dynamically allocate the memory so that the memory remains valid:

```
std::function<void(void)>* handler = new std::function<void()>(std::bind(&A::onEventFunc, this));
```

However, you would be then required to `delete` the memory to avoid memory leaks, so another alternative would be to use `std::unique_ptr` in your map to handle that.

Comment: Thank you! I changed the map to hold the std::function as you suggested and it now works. I knew I was doing something really stupid. So the problem was that when it created "handler" on the stack and then used the pointer it was pointing to nothing since the "handler" was destroyed when the function exited.

Comment: @user3348501: Yes, that is exactly what is happening. Nice job!